# Passing data between views and load a string to Text View

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I have a `NSMutableArray` in a view where I parse some JSON data to a Table View. Now, when I click on a cell I want to pass the value (text) of the selected cell array to a `UITextView` in another view.

The `NSMutableArray` where I store the data is called movies.

Here's my code for the first view:

```
@interface DEMOSecondViewController ()  

@end

@implementation DEMOSecondViewController
@synthesize tableView = _tableView, activityIndicatorView = _activityIndicatorView;
@synthesize fontForCellText;
@synthesize btnFaceBook, btnTwitter, btnTwitter2;
@synthesize strURLToLoad;
@synthesize movies;

- (IBAction)showButtonMenu {
    [self.frostedViewController presentMenuViewController];
}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];

    strURLToLoad = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    [btnFaceBook setTitle:@"link-1" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [btnTwitter setTitle:@"link-2" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [btnTwitter2 setTitle:@"link-3" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

    [btnFaceBook setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnFaceBook setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [btnTwitter setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnTwitter setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [btnTwitter2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnTwitter2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostsObject" owner:self options:nil];
    PostsObject *cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    fontForCellText = cell.title.font;
    cellTextWidth = cell.title.frame.size.width;
    cellHeightExceptText = cell.frame.size.height - cell.title.frame.size.height;

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    self.activityIndicatorView.color = [UIColor greenColor];

    self.activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicatorView];
    [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    movies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self btnFromTabBarClicked:btnFaceBook];
}

- (void)loadJSONFromCurrentURL
{
    [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURLToLoad]];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        [movies setArray:JSON];
        [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];

    [operation start];
}

- (IBAction)btnFromTabBarClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    btnFaceBook.selected = btnTwitter.selected = btnTwitter2.selected = NO;

    sender.selected = YES;

    [strURLToLoad setString:[sender titleForState:UIControlStateDisabled]];

    [self loadJSONFromCurrentURL];
}

// Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return movies.count;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        static NSString *Identifier1 = @"TableHeaderView";


        TableHeaderView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableHeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (TableHeaderView *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            return cell;
        }

    } else {
        static NSString *Identifier2 = @"PostsObject";

        PostsObject *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier2];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostsObject" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (PostsObject *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }

        NSDictionary *movie = [self.movies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *strText = [movie objectForKey:[self getTextKey]];

        CGRect rect = cell.title.frame;
        rect.size.height = [self getHeightForText:strText];
        cell.title.frame = rect;
        cell.title.text = strText;
        cell.arrow.center = CGPointMake(cell.arrow.frame.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height/2);
        cell.published.text = [movie objectForKey:[self getPostedTime]];
        cell.twitterName.text = [movie objectForKey:[self getTwitterName]];

        return cell;

    }
    return 0;
}

//When I click on the cell, I want the selected cell-text to pass to another view
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //How can I do this?
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 224;

    } else {
        NSDictionary *movie = [self.movies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *strText = [movie objectForKey:[self getTextKey]];

        CGFloat cellHeight = cellHeightExceptText + [self getHeightForText:strText];
        return cellHeight;
    }

}

- (NSString *)getTextKey
{
    return btnTwitter.selected?@"tweet":@"message";
}

- (NSString *)getPostedTime
{
    return btnTwitter.selected?@"posted":@"published";
}

- (NSString *)getTwitterName
{
    return btnTwitter2.selected?@"user":@"usernew";
}

- (CGFloat)getHeightForText:(NSString *)strText
{
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(cellTextWidth, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [strText sizeWithFont:fontForCellText constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    NSLog(@"labelSize.height = %f",labelSize.height);
    return labelSize.height;
}

@end
```

And the code so far for the Second View looks like this:

```
@interface PostsNextView : UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *theMovie;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

@end
```

So how can I get the value from the first view to pass and display in the Text View in this file?

Answer (score 0):

Add to didSelectRowAtIndexPath code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //get the data you want to pass
    NSDictionary *movie = [self.movies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Allocate second view you want to open
    PostsNextView *newView = [[PostsNextView alloc] init];
    // pass the data 
    newView.theMovie = movie;
    // present view
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
}
```

And in PostsNextView.m file in viewDidLoad you can show the text you want to show.

//Extended

Add property to keep track which button was pressed:

```
@interface PostsNextView : UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *theMovie;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property  int whichButton;

@end
```

in view did load add this line:

```
newView.theMovie = movie;
newView.whichButton = _witchBtn;
```

In your DEMOSecondViewController.m file add ivar:

```
@implementation DEMOSecondViewController
{
    int _witchBtn;
}
```

And in the same file assign value to _witchBtn for example 0 as a default (all buttons disabled) if you change it to let's say Facebook assign _witchBtn = 1, if twitter _witchBtn = 2, etc.

Comment: Ok, it works. But as you can see in the first view, I have 3 different links I'm parsing. How can I set an if-statement in viewDidLoad in PostsNextView? Like, if the btnFacebook is selected: textView.text = [theMovie objectForKey:@"message"]; and if btnTwitter is selected: textView.text = [theMovie objectForKey:@"tweet"]; ? @Greg

Comment: You can add new property to PostsNextView.h for example @property int buttonType; and you can pass which button was pressed in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: after that in viewDidLoad you can use self. buttonType to set up your logic.

Comment: Hm, I can't figure it out right. Could you help me a bit with the code? @Greg